# how to find a name from a phonebook string in O(logn)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I got this question from an interview, I think I need to run a binary search, however, I can't figure out the implementation, can you please help me out.

The questions were, given a file, which has names and phone numbers.

These names and numbers are formated:

1. name and number is split by space
2. different name is split by `\n`

Also, the names are sorted.

The question is, given a name, output it's number if exists.

e.g.

`a 123\nb 234\nd 987\n`

find the number of `b`,

The output should be `234`

The algorithm should be O(logN) of time complexity.

**Edit**

The given function signature is

`func findNumber(phonebook string) string`

Comment: Do you know if your interviewers assumed that lengths of names have an upper limit?

Answer (score -1):

The next implementation of binary search assumes that there are `N` pairs of names and phone numbers stored in a list:

```py
def search(lines, name):
    l = 0
    r = len(lines)
    while l + 1 < r:
        m = (l + r) // 2
        if lines[m][0] <= name:
            l = m
        else:
            r = m
    return lines[l][1] if lines[l][0] == name else None

print(search([("a", "123"), ("b", "234"), ("c", "987")], "b")) # returned value "234"
print(search([("a", "123"), ("b", "234"), ("c", "987")], "d")) # returned value None
```

It returns the phone number if its user is available. The running time is O(MlogN) where M is length of `name` and N the size of the `lines` list. You can argue that names have an upper limit in terms of length, let's say 100000000 characters :-P, so actual running time is O(logN).

About the code:
The range of consideration is `[l, r)`, i.e, inclusive on the left side and exclusive on the right side.

Comment: If you argue that the length of names is limited, you can solve the problem in O(1) time. To get N distinct names, you need the length of names to grow at least like log N, so your lower bound is more like O((log N)^2). It's not clear to me if a smarter binary search can do better than this, by limiting the characters tested.

Comment: No, if the length of names is limited you cannot solve the problem in O(1) if the alphabet is infinite. Also, in time complexity size of the alphabet always matters.

Comment: @EloyPérezTorres thanks for your input. They didn't say if the name has a length limit or not. But I believe your assumption is reasonable tho.  The thing I didn't make clear was the function signature, I'm updating. Since the signature they provided is giving you the whole string not lines

Comment: @IanZhang O(MlogN) is the best achievable running time you can get from such problem. You can prove it using an adversarial strategy.